# angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the angular-ui-bootstrap library to implement the bootstrap modal - see [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

All is good, the modal is opening, but it will not close. I have tried to use `$uibModalInstance` but when I attempt to close the modal, as per the example in the link above this I get the following message:

> angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uibModalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20%24uibModalInstance%20%3C-%20testCtrl

I am using Angular version 1.5.3, [ui-bootstrap-tpls v1.3.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js) and [bootstrap css 3.3.6](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css)

My code looks like the following. I have attempted all answers dealing with the same issue on this, but cannot resolve the issue. I think there is an issue with the angular version, but before I go and play around with the version of angular I want to make sure there is nothing I am missing out. I thought [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487541/uibmodalinstance-close-not-working) would work, but no such luck.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider. 
       when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'app/views/address-book.html',
         controller: 'testCtrl as ctrl'
       }).
       otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
       });
})

.controller('testCtrl', ['$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance', function ($uibModal, $uibModalInstance) {

    this.open = function () {
        testCtrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/form.html',
          controller: 'testCtrl as ctrl'
        });
    }

    this.close = function() {
        console.log(testCtrl.modalInstance) //this shows undefined
        testCtrl.modalInstance.close();
    }
}]);
```

**html**

```
<a class="enterNewAddressBtn" ng-click="ctrl.open()">Enter new address</a>
```

**form.html**

```
<form>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.name" type="text">
    <button class="cancel-btn" ng-click="ctrl.close()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: why is it being marked down without any solution?

Comment: do no use minified version of angular to see described errors!

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki same error even when not minified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error shown because you want to inject `$uibModalInstanceProvider` before create modal Instance .If you use different controller and inject `$uibModalInstance` in modalInstance controller then this error will be remove.

Better to use different controller for `$uibModal` and `$uibModalInstance`. The `$uibModalInstance` represents a modal window (instance) dependency it is not the same as the `$uibModal` service. Modal open using `$uibModal` and close using `$uibModalInstance`.

You can get Idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330106/why-ng-repeat-is-not-working-if-button-invoked-from-a-different-form/36390401#36390401)  and for more details can visit plunker example [from here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ssz1tghgcWVZfNWXzF8A?p=preview).

It may will help you

Comment: but there is still an issue with the injecting the `$uibModalInstance` as per title of the question `angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr]......`

Comment: this error shown because you want to inject `$uibModalInstanceProvider` before create modal Instance .If you use different controller and inject `$uibModalInstance` in modalInstance controller  then this error will be remove.

Comment: @shishab roy, that works, but now I am having difficulties accessing the data in the `testCtrl`

Comment: plunker example accessed parent controller data and functions. I described in that question answer how access parent data and functions. hopefully that helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly you can't inject $uibModalInstance before you've created the modal using $uibModal.open();

move the injection of $uibModalInstance to the touchnoteCtrl and it should work fine.

Comment: can you look at the updated code... there is only one controller, `testCtrl` --- there was a problem with my example.. it is correct now